# Cannot drop Postgres trigger function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Code:

```
DROP function IF EXISTS update_rarity;
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  update_rarity() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    if  (((select count(raresa) FROM Carta WHERE c.raresa LIKE '%Legendary%')*100  /(select count(raresa) FROM Carta)) <> 17 ) then
        INSERT INTO Warnings(affected_table,error_message,date,user)
        VALUES ('Carta' ,'Proporcions de raresa no respectades: Legendary la proporció actual és '|| (select count(raresa) FROM Carta WHERE raresa LIKE '%Legendary%')  || 'quan hauria de ser 3', CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_USER);
    end if;
    
    return null;    
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql; 

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS cards ON Carta;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cards
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON  Carta
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION update_rarity();
```

```
UPDATE carta  SET nom ='Ral Roachs Rascals' ,raresa='Proletari' WHERE nom = 'Rascals';
```

```
ERROR:  syntax error in or near of «;»
LINE 1: DROP function IF EXISTS update_rarity;
                                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 38
```

Comment: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible. Your code would work with all supported Postgres versions.

Answer (score 2):

The possibility to omit the function signature for a DROP FUNCTION was introduced in Postgres 10. In your outdated and unsupported Postgres version, you need to include the parameter list (which is empty for a trigger function):

```
DROP function IF EXISTS update_rarity();
                                     ^-- this
```

Comment: Okey thank you for all,you are alright,it is the version.Solutioned